# python- How can I convert a year, month, week (number of a week in the month) to get the first day of that week?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to convert the format of date given as (Year-Month-Week number) to get the 1st date of that week.

The input in the files is March 2020, Week 2. Is there a way in which I can the first day of the week as 10/03/2020.

2nd example - Feb 2020, Week 1. The expected output is 02/02/2020.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: To make the problem more simple, assuming each week starts on Sunday, you are essentially finding the Nth Sunday of the given month

Comment: @dspencer Thanks for replying. I gave it a try by converting a week number (of each month) to week number (of each year) and then using time.asctime(time.strptime('{} {} 1'.format(year, week), '%Y %W %w')) to convert it  to date time format but the number of weeks are dynamic so this function won't work as expected